# Taking screenshot with Win32 API (C# pInvoke) not working in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows, winapi, iis

I want to take a screenshot of an external website.
Currently my workflow is to start a Firefox instance with the specified URL and take a screenshot using PrintWindow in the Win32 API

When I run this application in IISExpress it works fine but when I run the same application in IIS on a windows VPS it is not working (screenshot is blank).

I don't know what I'm doing wrong?

My code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;

namespace WebTools.Web
{
    public class RemoteScreenshot
    {
        public static Bitmap TakeScreenshot(Process process)
        {
            // may need a process Refresh before
            return TakeScreenshot(process.MainWindowHandle);
        }

        public static Bitmap TakeScreenshot(IntPtr handle)
        {
            RECT rc = new RECT();
            GetWindowRect(handle, ref rc);

            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);

            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                PrintWindow(handle, graphics.GetHdc(), 0);
            }

            return bitmap;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT rect);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC, int flags);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct RECT
        {
            public int left;
            public int top;
            public int right;
            public int bottom;
        }

        public static void Save(string url, string file, int timeout = 0)
        {
            var proc = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe", url)
            {
                CreateNoWindow = false,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized
            });

            Thread.Sleep(timeout);

            var bitmap = TakeScreenshot(proc);

            bitmap.Save(file, ImageFormat.Png);
            bitmap.Dispose();

            proc.Kill();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Running Firefox works fine because the AppPool is under another account that has the rights to execute firefox.

Comment: How is it not working? Does it throw an exception? Chances are you're hitting a code access boundary and it's throwing an UnauthorizedException

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I run the apppool with a user-identity. I'm eventualy getting a ArgumentException on the Bitmap constructor part because the width and height of the screen can't be calculated but when I set this to 1600x900 it is also not working.

Comment: You'll need to add some logging. Log the values you're passing into the bitmap constructor.

Comment: I know what values are passed, 0 and 0 because the 'GetWindowRect' function returns that. But when I pass 1600x900 to the constructor I get a blank image.

Comment: Are you sure that the user account that you run the IIs pool with has been initialized properly, with a proper user profile (think %USERPROFILE%) and such? I would imagine that Firefox needs a user profile to work properly.

Comment: If you're getting 0,0 from `GetWindowRect`, then your window handle is wrong.

Comment: @Magnus I think so, when I check the task manager then I see that the process is created.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead That's weird because 'GetLastError' in the Win32 API returns '0' ..

Comment: @DillenMeijboom just because the process is created doesn't mean that Firefox actually does what you expect. Imagine what happens when you first run Firefox as a new user, does it a) start a first time use wizard/import wizard or b) immediately show you a blank browser ready to use?

Comment: @Magnus Hmm, I guess your right. But still if the 'new-user-screen' is shown then the Screenshot application should still take a screen shot right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What screen are you taking a screenshot of?

If an application is running on a laptop it will paint to a physical display adaptor.  If it is running on a machine at the end of an RDP session it will paint to a virtual display adaptor, and the image will be sent over the wire.

But if an application is running in a non-interactive session then there is no display.  [The application won't receive WM_PAINT messages](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/zh-TW/0c37753d-701a-44a2-8659-276d90dac820/noninteractive-desktops-do-not-send-wmpaint-messages?forum=windowssdk) so nothing gets painted.

There is no screen bitmap to capture.

Comment: Hmmm, the application is running on a virtual private server from CloudVPS. But is there a way to make a session interactive or something?

Comment: @DillenMeijboom If you're on XP you might get away with it but Vista and later try to avoid interactivity as much as possible: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @ta.speot.is I shall take a look at it, I'm currently running Windows 8 server on my VPS.

Answer (score 0):

Using IIS you can't take Screen Shot as It works under NetworkService Account in Windows server

Comment: I can because I'm using the 'user-identity' settings in IIS to run the AppPool under another account than the NetworkService account.

Comment: The IIS service is likely non-interactive and child processes will inherit that.

Comment: I had similar problem with windows server, When I couldn't find a proper solution within time, I ended up writing a WCF Service Hosted on a console application as it was not working even in windows service.

Answer (score -2):

IIS service donot have the access to the server desktop. The code of ASP.NET in IIS is running on the server side. And it will be trying to capture the screen of the server, which is denied.

You will need to use the silverlight which runs the code on the client machine.
Following link might help:

[Capturing a Silverlight Screen](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Capturing-a-Silverlight-Screen.aspx)

User using the webpage in the browser might need to provide permissions due to security reasons.

Comment: I don't want to use Silverlight and since it works local I'm sure with some help I can make it work online ;)

Comment: There will not be anyway to capture the screen of client from the server side.
Please see my edited answer.

Comment: I'm 100% sure that I can make it work, the user I've created has permissions to open Firefox and I can capture the screen using the Win32 API to make a screenshot of the Firefox browser.